# my sum function error and dont show nothing

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript code
I use the total for count diskon and then I using total, diskon and bayar for count kembali.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function sum() {
      var total = document.getElementById('txtTotal').value;
      if (total >= 75000) {
        var diskon = parseInt(total) * 0.15;
        document.getElementById('txtDiskon').value = diskon;
      } else if (total >= 50000 & <=74999) {
        var diskon = parseInt(total) * 0.10;
        document.getElementById('txtDiskon').value = diskon;
      } 
      else if (total >= 25000 & <=49000) {
        var diskon = parseInt(total) * 0.05;
        document.getElementById('txtDiskon').value = diskon;
      } 
      else if (total >= 0 & <=24999) {
        var diskon = 0;
        document.getElementById('txtDiskon').value = diskon;
      }
      var bayar = document.getElementById('txtBayar').value;
      var kembali = parseInt(bayar) - (parseInt(total) - parseInt(diskon));

      if (!isNaN(kembali)) {
         document.getElementById('txtKembali').value = kembali;
      }
</script>
```

And this is my html code

```
<input name="total" id="txtTotal" onkeyup="sum();" type="text"/>
<input name="diskon" id="txtDiskon" onkeyup="sum();" type="text" />
<input name="bayar" id="txtBayar" onkeyup="sum(); "type="text" />
<input name="kembali" id="txtKembali" type="text"/>
```

The problem is when I make the "else if" my javascript code is not show the "diskon" and nothing error more. And now I don't know where is the bug one, Please help me fix it

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior.

Comment: Of course, I am using the term _question_ as a figure of speech, as there is no question asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Update your `condition total >= 50000 && total <=74999 rather than total >=50000 & <= 74999.` same for other between condition. Look at [&& operator][1]

```js
function sum() {
      var total = document.getElementById('txtTotal').value;
      if (total >= 75000) {
        var diskon = parseInt(total) * 0.15;
        document.getElementById('txtDiskon').value = diskon;
      } else if (total >= 50000 && total <=74999) {
        var diskon = parseInt(total) * 0.10;
        document.getElementById('txtDiskon').value = diskon;
      } 
      else if (total >= 25000 && total <=49000) {
        var diskon = parseInt(total) * 0.05;
        document.getElementById('txtDiskon').value = diskon;
      } 
      else if (total >= 0 && total <=24999) {
        var diskon = 0;
        document.getElementById('txtDiskon').value = diskon;
      }
      var bayar = document.getElementById('txtBayar').value;
      var kembali = parseInt(bayar) - (parseInt(total) - parseInt(diskon));

      if (!isNaN(kembali)) {
         document.getElementById('txtKembali').value = kembali;
      }
}
```

```html
    <input name="total" id="txtTotal" onkeyup="sum()" type="text">
    <input name="diskon" id="txtDiskon" onkeyup="sum()" type="text" >
    <input name="bayar" id="txtBayar" onkeyup="sum()" type="text" >
    <input name="kembali" id="txtKembali" type="text">
```

```
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND
```